# What's the difference between delete[] arr and deleting elements in a loop

Tags: c++, arrays

***Context:***
I need to move all elements from an array to a new array. The old array is to be destroyed after the copy.

***Code:***

```
int* array = new int[5];
int* newArray = new int[5];
```

Option 1: destroy elements in the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  newArray[i] = array[i];
  delete (array + i);
}
```

Option 2: using delete[]

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  newArray[i] = array[i];
}
delete[] array;
```

***Questions:***
What's the difference? Is delete[] more efficient than option1 (Does delete[] destroy a block of memory instead of erasing element by element? )?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, option 1 exhibits undefined behavior, so the difference is one of correct code and incorrect code.

You can only `delete` (or, in this case, `delete[]`) what was returned from `new`.  The individual elements of the array were not returned by new (nor are they pointers).  Calling `delete` on a pointer which was not returned by `new`, i.e., `array + n` invokes undefined behavior.

An implementation of `new` may allocate a bit more memory than was requested for bookkeeping.  It gets a pointer, `p`, and then says "ok, now let's look at the info `new` created for me at `p - sizeof(some_structure)`.  Now I know that I allocated `n` bytes of memory because `some_structure.n` tells me so, so I'll clean that up now".

When it attempts to do that on the erroneous pointer you gave it it reads nonsense and anything can happen.

---

On a side note, prefer `std::copy` to copy an array, not a loop.

Comment: Hi Ed. I got your point! Now I am curious about if " new int[3] " is equal to " new int(); new int(); new int(); " ? Are these dynamically created integers stored in heap memory instead of stack?

Comment: @lichgo: The spec does not mention a "heap" or a "stack" as they are implementation details, but yes, in every implementation I know of it will be allocated on a heap structure dynamically (as opposed to variables with automatic storage duration which are located on the stack.) `new int()` returns a pointer to a single `int`, and you would free it with `delete p`.  `new int[n]` returns a pointer to `n` `int`s and you delete it with `delete [] p`. The rule is; if you use `new []` then you free with `delete []`.  Otherwise, you use `delete`, and you only ever `delete` what was returned by `new`.

Comment: @lichgo your premise is wrong. those things are not equivalent. Regardless, where the implementation stores the stuff is up to it; you're only concern as a language client is that it *can* (and does).

Comment: "new and delete will almost certainly allocate a bit more" - this is often true of `new[]` as it needs to keep track of the number of elements so `delete[]` can iterate calling destructors, but for "plain" `new` many implementations will have a set of small fixed-sized areas (e.g. 8 byte capacity) and any pointer inside that area's size is implicitly known, and for other areas the size may be tracked outside the allocated area (e.g. in a distinct free list/tree).

Answer (score 1):

`delete` and `delete[]` are fundamentally different (one cannot replace the other).

`delete a` deallocates the memory pointed to by `a`.

```
 a
 |
 v
 Abcde
```

`delete[]` deallocates the memory **for the array** starting at `a`.

```
 a
 |
 v
 AbcdeAbcdeAbcdeAbcde
```

The first is not for an array; the second is for an array.